# Lottery probability calculation

Tags: probability

i have a question about lottery probability. Here it is:

There are a total of 60 numbers.
You have to choose 10 numbers.
20 of those 60 numbers are chosen as lucky ones.
Whats the probability that all of your 10 numbers are lucky ones? 9 of your 10 are lucky ones? Etc..

Could you please explain to me how to calculate this probability

Comment: Does the phrase "Hypergeometric probability" ring any bells? That is exactly what you need to calculate the probability that the overlap of your selection of $10$ numbers and their selection of $20$ numbers is of a specific size.

Comment: Thank you Arthur. One more question. I've got some info now about hypergeometric probability, just want to make sure. Here is what i found:
N = size of population

So in my example N=60; M=10, n=20, k=10 right?
M = # of items in population with property "E"
N-M = # of items in population without property "E"
n = number of items sampled
k = number of items in sample with property "E"

P(k) = (M,k)*(N-M,n-k) / (N,n)

In general, the "symbol" (a,b) means combinations of "a items, taking b of them:"
(a,b) = aCb = a! / (b!(a-b)!)

So in my example N=60, M=10; n=20, k=10 right?

Comment: Yes, and then you keep decreasing $k$ if you want the probability of $9, 8$ etc. drawn lucky numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness and based on Arthur's and your comments, if the total number of possible numbers is $N=60$, the number of numbers you pick is $M=10$, the total number of lucky numbers is $n=20$ and the number of lucky numbers you pick is $k$ then using the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) the probability of $k$ is $$\frac{\displaystyle {K \choose k}{N-M \choose n-k}}{\displaystyle {N \choose n}}$$ and inthis particular case would give the following rounded probabilities

```
 k  Probability 
10  0.0000025
 9  0.0000891
 8  0.0013032
 7  0.0101586
 6  0.0469835
 5  0.1353125
 4  0.2466635
 3  0.2819011
 2  0.1938070
 1  0.0725360
 0  0.0112431
```

which (apart from minor rounding) add up to $1$.